# How to plan your own spiritual path

Tags: vedas, scripture, yoga

In this times It is really energy consuming to learn from different organization or modern man about spiritual guidence and to have all the time this filter in the head filtering the nonsense and conflicting actions from their preaching and life that they are living.

And more and more people are suffering after many years of learning from someone who is showing conflicts in their life and preaching. For example Swamis that are exploiting devoties etc... I know that if one rotten fruit is in the basket you can't expect that are all rotten, but still if you don't have nose or eyes that could see, you can't test them untill you bite them and see for your self if you are sick.

So with all that I want to ask:

- What kind of quidance systems hinduism provide in a mater of this question, so that one can enter and walks spiritual, with a safe and well defined matter, alone and independent.
- What dusty old books would you suggest so they will be good replacement for the guru from Himalaya, that have as little distortion from modern men as possible.

Comment: Questions asking for personal advice is not allowed. Please edit your question so it is not asking for personal advice if you want it to remain.

Comment: why not refer to the Patanjali Yoga Sutras. it contains 8 detailed steps to plan your spititual journey towards the final Goal or God. They are given here: http://www.swamij.com/yoga-sutras-22629.htm. All the best dear friend. As Swamiji says this site is not suitable for personal opinions but you can easily convert this question into a non-personal one by editing your three questions into something that is general and applicable to all seekers of Yoga or Union with That

Comment: Oh Yes I will transfere it in to more sutable question, thank you.

Comment: @urosjarc Opinion-based questions aren't allowed on this site, so you should remove the part about "What is your view on this problem, in this modern times?".

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I was not aware obout this... fixed

Answer (score 0):

The Bhagavad Gita is one of the most sacred scripture that teaches humans all about life and right from wrong. Personally it gives me great peace when I listen to it. To live up to lord Krishna's standards these days might seem impossible however atleast if you try and follow your moral compass. It will not only make you feel good about yourself, but also give you great inner peace. Always try to do what is right and do it for yourself not for rewards and not for praise. And always remember if you do something wrong, and realize it, if you confess to God and make a genuine effect not to reapet it, he will always forgive you. Always. And that is what makes god different from humans...

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: Source: me. No other website used.

Comment: Well, answers on this site are supposed to be backed up with details and sources (preferably scripture).  So please find sources to support your answer or it's liable to be deleted.

Comment: The answere is accepted since I ask for "What is your view on this problem, in this modern times?". @HarshaKalagana: So thank you for your input, any help is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The living tradition of Gurus are like a guiding light that has shown the path from time immemorial. Just because few fake Godmen are at fault, does not mean all Guru's are fake.

The scriptures ask people to examine a guru well before accepting him but have unflinching shraddha/faith after accepting a Guru subsequent to a proper examination. So, that is one path.

If, that is not suitable, then you can read works of past Guru's like Bhagavad gita, works of Adi Shankara etc. and practice their teachings.

If you are bent towards devotion by temperament, you should practice devotional practies like japa, fire ritual etc. The God himself/herself will guide you.

This is a website which provides simple procedures for performing Homam to various deities- http://vedicastrologer.org/homam/index.htm

Regards,
Nithin